# How control the Mavic Air drone with the computer

Tags: dji-sdk

right now, I’m on a study project for School. I'm french. I have the **Mavic Air** drone, and **I do to control my drone with my computer.** DJI Developer has some SDK for different plateforme, whose a Windows SDK. But it was in beta version and he don't support the fly mod.
I think, to take the OX SDK (Android Version in JAVA) and translate it into a Java App for a Windows version. OX SDK support drone control commands. You thinks it's a good ideas ? And some people can help to translate this app ? 
Can you help me find a solution? Have you some command-line to give to me?
Thanks you all.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear from your question if you've actually tried to implement the Windows 10 SDK and ran into difficulties or if you saw something which stated flight is not supported by the SDK. According to the SDK documentation (https://developer.dji.com/windows-sdk/), high & low level flight control are supposed to be supported. For example, the ComponentManager.FlightControllerHandler has methods such as StartTakeoffAsync, StartGoHomeAsync, etc. Joystick control is available via the VirtualRemoteController.UpdateJoystickValue method. So far, I have only used these while my Mavic Air is in simulation mode (without propellers on!) and haven't encountered any issues. But I haven't seen any documentation that states the beta SDK doesn't support actual flight either. Before launching into a conversion effort (does DJI even provide the source? I haven't checked...), I'd stick with with Win10 SDK.

Comment: Have you do test to controle your drone by it ? I would like control my drone with the coumputer ... I have tried the Windows SDK .. and i can't start the simulator. can you help me ?

Comment: Sorry, the code was developed for a client so cannot be shared. What issues are you experiencing? Have you registered your app with DJI? Have you been able to get the sample solution running?

Comment: Can I take your email address to send a picture of the process. I have registered my application on dji. I managed to get him off the ground. Just now. and little anecdote, I was not ready, and I cut myself a piece of nail. For simulation, i do install DJISimulator ? i can't tip my account information to connect.

Comment: Subsequently, I will like to control the drone with the computer. What lines should I use to control it with a controller?

Comment: For simulation mode, just call the flight controller handler's StartSimulatorAsync method. You'll just need to provide it with GPS coordinates & a satellite count. Email address is in my profile.

Comment: I managed to get him off the ground. but I can not land it. How can i do it

Comment: I'd suggest looking at the Windows.Gaming.Input namespace (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.gaming.input) to handle gamepad events and use those to update the DJI SDK (for example, LeftThumbstick for throttle & yaw, RightThumbstick for pitch and roll).

Comment: And it work with WSDK ? Where can I insert the code? first, I would like just create button to move it. So, How can i land it? just like this:
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ufEdo.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/keB4M.png

Comment: I tried to crate the same with  https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/windows-api/Components/FlightControllerHandler.html#flightcontrollerhandler_startautolandingasync_inline  picture of code with landingasync[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYqvH.png

Comment: I managed to land it ,. and to move it how can I do it? In what code part can I work for that?

Comment: How to connect the controler with the pc and control drone with it ?